# Bulk append file names in a directory using Python

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x, url

I've just started with Python and this is my first 'own' program. I've explained (to the best of my ability) what I intend my program to achieve. Since I'm new, I'd appreciate any syntax/performance improvement suggestions you may have.

```
   '''
        Search through a target movies directory and filter movie titles
        to search IMDb for movie ratings. After fetching, append ratings
        to corresponding movie files/folders in the directory.

        File names are in one of the following formats:
        1. P.S. I Love You.mkv
        2. P.S. I Love You (2010).mp4
        3. P.S. I Love You (2010) [1080p].avi

        Ideally, this program fetched the movie ratings and adds it to
        the end of the file name (just before the extension). The query,
        in this case, would be http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=P.S.+I+Love+You

        Ideally, the file in the directory would be renamed to one of the
        following:
        1. P.S. I Love You (7.1).mkv
        2. P.S. I Love You (2010) (7.1).mp4
        3. P.S. I Love You (2010) [1080p] (7.1).avi
    '''

    import os, json, urllib.request, re

    # Query related constants
    base_uri = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?"
    query_title = "t="

    basepath = "E:/Movies"

    # Fetch movie rating from omdbapi.com
    # Example JSON response: http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=insurgent
    def getRating(movie_title):
        # json_response = urllib.urlopen(base_uri + query_title + movie_title)
        # movie_data = json.loads(json_response.read())
        with urllib.request.urlopen(base_uri + query_title + movie_title) as url:
            movie_data = url.read()
        return movie_data['imdbRating']

    # Checks if parameter file name already has a rating.
    # Movie ratings are
    def hasRating(filename):
        pattern = re.compile('\([0-9].[0-9]\)')
        if pattern.search(filename) is not None:
            return True
        return False

    # Get the movie title by stripping out excess information such as the
    # year released or video definition
    def getMovieTitle(filename):
        if '(' not in filename is False:
            return filename.split('(')[0]
        elif'[' not in filename is False:
            return filename.split('[')[0]
        return os.path.splitext(basepath + filename)[:-1]


    def main():
        for file in os.listdir(basepath):
            if hasRating(file) is False:
                movie_title = getMovieTitle(file)
                file_ext = os.path.splitext(basepath + file)[-1:]
                movie_rating = getRating(movie_title)
                formatted_rating = ' (' + movie_rating + ')'
                file_no_ext = os.path.splitext(basepath + file)[:-1]

                os.rename(file, file_no_ext + ' ' + formatted_rating + file_ext)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I've tried to fix everything I can so far but I keep arriving at the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renamer.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "renamer.py", line 58, in main
    movie_rating = getRating(movie_title)
  File "renamer.py", line 33, in getRating
    with urllib.request.urlopen(base_uri + query_title + movie_title) as url:
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

Please let me know what a `TypeError` is, why it occurs, and what I can do to fix it.

Coming from Java, the simplicity of Python is kind of overwhelming but refreshing at the same time. Anyway, thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `getMovieTitle` returns a tuple if no `if` condition is true. So `movie_title` is a tuple and `getRating` can't handle that ("adding" of strings and tuples results in a `TypeError` exception).

Returning the last element of a list is done by `[-1]`. What you expect to use from `os.path.splitext` is the first part, so use index 0.

```
return os.path.splitext(basepath + filename)[:-1]
```

turn this line to

```
return os.path.splitext(basepath + filename)[0]
```

Second, you're accessing  `movie_data` which is a string after reading with `url.read()` by `movie_data['imdbRating']`. What you most probably want is to decode the result (which is json) and then access the element:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(base_uri + query_title + movie_title) as url:
    movie_data = json.loads(url.read())['imdbRating']
```

This works as long 'imdbRating' is a key in the root dictionary.

Comment: In that statement, I'm trying to return the file name without the extension. So, I return everything except the last part (extension) of the file name.

Comment: than use `''.join(os.path.splitext(basepath + filename)[:-1])`, this joins the values of the tuple by a empty string. `('a','b','c')` gets `'abc'`.

Comment: `splitext ` gives a a tuple with two values: `(root, ext)`. Use index 0 to get it to work as expected

Comment: I thought it returned a list of strings split by (presumably default) `.` characters.

Comment: No, it seperates the last extension. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) on `splitext`. `os.path.splitext('test.doc.exe')` returns `('test.doc', 'exe')`.

Comment: That makes sense. What happens when, let's say, a folder is the parameter? In other words, what if the parameter had no real extension? Would `os.path.splitext('foobar')` return `('foobar', '')`?

Comment: Exactly, try it in your interactive python shell.

Comment: Alright, I tried it out and the splitting works as intended. However, I now have another `TypeError`:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renamer.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "renamer.py", line 63, in main
    movie_rating = getRating(movie_title)
  File "renamer.py", line 38, in getRating
    return movie_data['imdbRating']
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str` 

I tried to wrap `movie_data['imdbRating']` with `str()` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'll extend my answer